# Connect-MsolService blank screen

Tags: powershell

I want to setup SSO between GSuite (as Identitiy provider "IdP") and Microsoft 365.
When I want to connect to Microsoft 365 through powershell, I use the following command:

```
Install-Module MSOnline
Import-Module MSOnline
$msolCred = get-credential
Connect-MsolService -credential $msolCred
```

When I run the last command, I'll receive the following empty Microsoft login screen:

[image]

I thought maybe it's because of onedrive and other windows 10 services, I have logged out everywhere but still doesn't work. If someone can guide me, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by decreasing security of internet options (from control panel) from high to medium.